# PL/SQL in Oracle Error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I tried moving thing are around but no luck. Keep receiving the following error. Someone, Please advise.

```
Declare 

 Begin
FOR v_rec IN (
select max(TotalEmployee) as TotalEmployee1 , Week_Day 
    from (select count(*) as TotalEmployee,  TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'Day') as Week_Day  
           from Employee  
           group by TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'Day') 
    Order by TotalEmployee desc) Table1
    group by Week_Day
                    )LOOP   
    dbms_output.put_line('*********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************');      
    dbms_output.put_line(v_rec.Week_Day || (v_rec.TotalEmployee1)||' employee');
    dbms_output.put_line(rpad('Hire_Date', 15) ||  rpad('Name', 15) || rpad('JOB TITLE', 45) || rpad('SALARY', 20) || rpad( '# of EMP',15 ) || rpad('DEPARTMENT NAME',20) ||rpad( 'MANAGER NAME',15 ) || rpad( 'MANAGER SALARY',15 ));                             
    FOR v_rec1 IN (select HIRE_DATE , EMPLOYEE_NAME as Name , JOB_TITLE , 
                Case when SALARY = null then '-------' 
                     ELSE to_char( SALARY, '$9,999.99' ) 
                END   as "SALARY" ,
                Case when DEPARTMENT_NAME = null then '-------' 
                     ELSE DEPARTMENT_NAME 
                END as DEPARTMENT_NAME,
                Case when Employee_NAME = null then '-------'
                            ELSE Employee_NAME 
                        END as MANAGERNAME,
                Case when SALARY = null then '-------' 
                             ELSE to_char( SALARY, '$9,999.99' ) 
                        END   as MANAGERSALARY 
                from Employee, department
           where TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'Day') in (v_rec.Week_Day) and employee.DEPARTMENT_ID = department.DEPARTMENT_ID  ) LOOP

            dbms_output.put_line(rpad(v_rec1.HIRE_DATE, 15) ||  rpad(v_rec1.Name, 15) || rpad(v_rec1.JOB_TITLE, 45) || rpad(v_rec1.SALARY, 20) || rpad( '# of EMP',15 ) || rpad(v_rec1.DEPARTMENT_NAME,20) ||rpad( Employee_NAME,15 ) || rpad( SALARY,15 ));                             

    END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Keep receiving the following error. Someone please advise.

Error report -

```
ORA-06550: line 29, column 204:
PLS-00201: identifier 'EMPLOYEE_NAME' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 29, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: What is your interpretation of this very explicit error message, `identifier 'EMPLOYEE_NAME' must be declared`?

Comment: Confirm the column name from the table and use IS null instead of = null because null can not be compared with any value.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the below line, for everything except employee_name and salary, you correctly specify the v_rec1. For these two you do not, assuming you have not declared these variables elsewhere then this will give you the specified error.

```
dbms_output.put_line(rpad(v_rec1.HIRE_DATE, 15) ||  rpad(v_rec1.Name, 15) || rpad(v_rec1.JOB_TITLE, 45) || rpad(v_rec1.SALARY, 20) || rpad( '# of EMP',15 ) || rpad(v_rec1.DEPARTMENT_NAME,20) ||rpad( Employee_NAME,15 ) || rpad( SALARY,15 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some basic things you need to understamd while coding. `"NULL"` cant be compared to anything. We need to use `IS NULL/IS NOT NULL` to check for NULL conditions. The code seems ok as per the basic syntax, but need to confirm the column names as the error suggest there is a mismatch in the column identifier.Also avoid using `""` and `RESERVED` keywords in the code.Hope below snippet helps.

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  FOR v_rec IN
  (SELECT MAX(TotalEmployee) AS TotalEmployee1 ,
    Week_Day
  FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(*)            AS TotalEmployee,
      TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'Day') AS Week_Day
    FROM Employee
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'Day')
    ORDER BY TotalEmployee DESC
    ) Table1
  GROUP BY Week_Day
  )
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('*********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************');
    dbms_output.put_line(v_rec.Week_Day || (v_rec.TotalEmployee1)||' employee');
    dbms_output.put_line(rpad('Hire_Date', 15) || rpad('Name', 15) || rpad('JOB TITLE', 45) || rpad('SALARY', 20) || rpad( '# of EMP',15 ) || rpad('DEPARTMENT NAME',20) ||rpad( 'MANAGER NAME',15 ) || rpad( 'MANAGER SALARY',15 ));
    FOR v_rec1 IN
    (SELECT HIRE_DATE ,
      EMPLOYEE_NAME AS EMP_NAME ,
      JOB_TITLE ,
      CASE
        WHEN SALARY IS NULL
        THEN '-------'
        ELSE TO_CHAR( SALARY, '$9,999.99' )
      END AS "SALARY" ,
      CASE
        WHEN DEPARTMENT_NAME IS NULL
        THEN '-------'
        ELSE DEPARTMENT_NAME
      END AS DEPARTMENT_NAME,
      CASE
        WHEN Employee_NAME IS NULL
        THEN '-------'
        ELSE Employee_NAME
      END AS MANAGERNAME,
      CASE
        WHEN SALARY IS NULL
        THEN '-------'
        ELSE TO_CHAR( SALARY, '$9,999.99' )
      END AS MANAGERSALARY
    FROM Employee,
      department
    WHERE TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'Day') IN (v_rec.Week_Day)
    AND employee.DEPARTMENT_ID       = department.DEPARTMENT_ID
    )
    LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(rpad(v_rec1.HIRE_DATE, 15) || rpad(v_rec1.EMP_NAME, 15) || rpad(v_rec1.JOB_TITLE, 45) || rpad(v_rec1.SALARY, 20) || rpad( '# of EMP',15 ) || rpad(v_rec1.DEPARTMENT_NAME,20) ||rpad( Employee_NAME,15 ) || rpad( SALARY,15 ));
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives you a line number, so you know which line causes the problem. Line 29 is the long DBMS_OUTPUT call, starting `dbms_output.put_line(rpad(v_rec1.HIRE_DATE, 15)`.

The error message also gives you a column number. Column equates to characters (from the days when everything was fixed size fonts). Column 204 points to this element:

```
rpad( Employee_NAME,15 )
      ^
      204
```

The compiler works from left to right, so you know it is happy with everything that is to the left of this code. A comparison of the code shows that the "good" identifiers are all prefixed with the cursor name e.g. `rpad(v_rec1.HIRE_DATE, 15)`. PL/SQL needs all references to be identified in the correct namespace (the default is the DECLARE section). So the solution is to prepend the `Employee_NAME` -- and the `salary` -- references with the cursor name:  `rpad( v_rec1.Employee_NAME,15 )`.

PL/SQL errors aren't always this clear: syntax errors caused by missing commas or brackets can have line and/or column numbers which are a long way from the actual typo. But they aren't just random numbers, they contain useful clues for diagnosing our errors. It helps to have a decent program editor which shows line numbers and column numbers in the source code view.

---

Incidentally, this will never be true: `Employee_NAME = null`. NULL is special and to test for it you need the IS operator: `Employee_NAME is null`.